# How would I UPDATE these table entries with SQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am working on an Asset Database problem.

I enter assets into a database.  Every object is an asset and has variables within the asset table.  An object is also a type of asset.  In this example the type is server.

Here is the Query to retrieve all necessary data:

```
SELECT asset.id
,asset.company
,asset.location
,asset.purchaseDate
,asset.purchaseOrder
,asset.value
,asset.type
,asset.notes
,server.manufacturer
,server.model
,server.serialNumber
,server.esc
,server.warranty
,server.user
,server.prevUser
,server.cpu
,server.memory
,server.hardDrive
FROM asset
LEFT JOIN server
    ON server.id = asset.id
WHERE asset.id = '$id'
```

I then assign all results into single php variables.

How would I write a query/script to update an asset?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to perform the update of an asset? What information will you have at the time of your update: `id` from the asset table? Is `id` the primary key of the asset table? If so, the first update shown by Amadan will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have (presumably) a one-to-many relationship between assets and servers, you would need to update them separately:

```
UPDATE assets SET
    company = '$company',
    location = '$location', ...
WHERE id = $asset_id;

UPDATE servers SET
    manufacturer = '$manufacturer',
    model = '$model', ....
WHERE $id = $server_id
```

You will have to do the second query *n* times, where *n* is number of records of `server` associated with the particular `asset`.

Also, I do hope you're careful with those variables - we don't want [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) here.

**UPDATE:**

OK, so you have one-to-maybe-one into several tables. In that case why use `LEFT JOIN` at all? There shouldn't be a possibility a `server` is not already an `asset`, right? Anyway, answer, off the top of my head:

```
UPDATE assets, servers
SET
    assets.company = ...,
    servers.manufacturer = ...
WHERE assets.id = $id
AND servers.id = $id
```

Comment: I may be showing my misunderstanding but I do not have a one to many relationship.  An asset can be a server, desktop, or laptop.  An asset can not be many servers, many desktops, or many laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a 1-1 connection between your asset table and your server table. It is essentially the same table. If you have control over your database layout, I would rethink it.

If not you will have to do two update calls, one to each table like @Amadan showed you

Comment: How would you consider changing the database structure?  Instead of having a table "assets" with half the objects variables and having the other half in table "servers", should I just have one table "servers" with all the variables?